# How can get connector name and task id inside a Custom Kafka Connect SMT at runtime?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have trying to emit custom metrics from a Kafka Connect SMT. However the problem is that I need the current connector name and task id at runtime to properly configure the MBean. It seems there is no way to get this info at runtime directly

Tried to get the information form the configure method in the SMT. But it seems this only contains SMT specific configs